# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar archivos usando ensamblador en windows de 64 bits?

Tags: ensamblador

Estoy creando un pequeño programa en ensamblador, usando visual studio con las librerías de Irvine. Dichas librerías tienen un procedimiento para crear archivos de varios tipos (.txt, .java entre otros) pero no cuenta con un procedimiento para eliminar esos archivos. En esta pagina encontré la función `mov ah,41h` la cual decía que era para eliminar el archivo de la ruta que se le especifica, pero al momento de querer utilizarla me da un error. ¿Alguno de ustedes conoce algún otro método para eliminar archivos en ensamblador?
Estoy usando ensamblador x86 en una computadora de 64 bits.